# Is there an easy way to log changes to an Access form?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, onchange, record

I'm thinking this is probably pretty simple, but I'm stuck on something.

A client has  form that has bound controls, so of course changing the value of that textbox updates the DB automatically. What we're looking for is a way to "log" the change, i.e. catch the change in progress, record the old value before the change, and put that info in a log table so we can record the change that was made. So if the value in the bound control was changed from "James" to "Jamey" then the log table would have both values along with a timestamp of when it was changed. I think the guy doesn't totally trust his employees (LOL) and wants to be able to in effect manually "roll back" a bad change. It's a bonus if we can also record the field.

I tried using the OnDirty event, but that's only after the fact I have no way to know what the old value was. I also used the BeforeChange event but OnDirty doesn't fire that event.

Comment: Not simple at all. Search for "audit trail".

Answer (score 0):

Probably on the Current Event of the form you should capture the value/s in question (the text of the textbox) and in the After Update compare what you have stored to the new value.
If there is a change then log the old value and proceed with the rest of the code.